How does Socket.IO work internally with AsyncRedisManager?
I have an application that uses Socket.io to implement websockets and is configured with Redis. The server side is written in Python, so I have something like this:
REDIS = f"redis://{settings.REDIS_USER}:{settings.REDIS_PASSWORD}@{settings.REDIS_HOST}:{settings.REDIS_PORT}/0"

mgr = AsyncRedisManager(REDIS, channel=settings.REDIS_CHANNEL)
sio = AsyncServer(
    async_mode="asgi", cors_allowed_origins="*", client_manager=mgr, logger=False
)  # logger=True, engineio_logger=True
sio.register_namespace(CommentsConnector("/comments"))
sio.register_namespace(DepartmentMessagesConnector("/department"))
sio.register_namespace(TeammateConnector("/teammate"))
sio.register_namespace(PersonalMessagesConnector("/personal"))
sio.register_namespace(SchedulerConnector("/snooze"))
sio.register_namespace(AssignConnector("/assign"))
sio.register_namespace(MailmanConnector("/mailman"))
sio.register_namespace(StatusConnector("/status"))
sio.register_namespace(DeleteInboxConnector("/delete-inbox"))
sio.register_namespace(DeleteUserConnector("/delete-user"))
sio.register_namespace(SearchConnector("/search-engine"))
sio.register_namespace(MoveToConnector("/move-to"))
sio.register_namespace(UpdateSessionMessages("/session"))
sio.register_namespace(MoveToCompletedMessages("/move-to-completed"))
sio_app = ASGIApp(sio)

I understand that Socket.IO using AsyncRedisManager uses the Redis Pub/Sub functionality, but I'm not sure how they integrate.
Socket.IO creates redis channels for each of the Rooms? or what is the policy/use that socket.io has for the creation and consumption of Redis Pub/Sub channels?
